# Find the sum of the first x members of the 2/(n^2-n) sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a specific name for sequences of the type of $\frac{2}{n^2-n}$? And is there a formula to find the sum of all consecutive members of such a sequence, where $n$ is between $x$ and $y$ ($>1$)?

Comment: Look up "telescoping series"